# Frequency of most repeated digit in a number in R

Tags: r

I am having troubles in find out frequency of the highest repeated digit within a number. I want output as following:

```
Number         Output
1111125436     5
9999266613     4
2346275210     3
1234567890     1
```

And so on.

I have tried `freqency`, `Biostrings`but couldn't do it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: This problem can be done in O(n) time using Moore's Linear Time Majority Vote Algorithm http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/. Python implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652492/python-find-majority-number-in-on-time-and-o1-memory

Comment: @kilojoules   R question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible `base` R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(Number = c(1111125436, 9999266613, 2346275210, 1234567890))
df$Output <- sapply(df$Number, function(x) tail(sort(table(strsplit(as.character(x), ''))), 1))
df
#       Number Output
# 1 1111125436      5
# 2 9999266613      4
# 3 2346275210      3
# 4 1234567890      1
```

Comment: `max(...)` is shorter to write and probably runs faster than `tail(sort(...),1)`

Comment: @Adam yeah, I have seen (and upvoted) the other answer using `max`, which will probably get more upvotes than mine -- but I'm leaving this alternative solution here as is.

Answer (score 5):

There could well be better ways than this, but splitting the number as a character string and table-ing seems like a possibility:

```
vapply(strsplit(as.character(dat$Number),""), function(x) max(table(x)), FUN.VALUE=1L)
#[1] 5 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option with `stri_count` and `pmax`

```
library(stringi)
do.call(pmax,lapply(0:9, stri_count_fixed, str=df1$Number))
#[1] 5 4 3 1
```

---

Or with `rowMaxs/stri_count`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMaxs(sapply(0:9, stri_count_fixed, str=df1$Number))
#[1] 5 4 3 1
```